# reversing word. (null terminated c string char array). why isn't it working

Tags: c, c-strings

am trying to reverse a char array and print it using %s. but its not working. am not getting anything printed. why is that? my code is pretty simple/

```
char* reverse(char* word){

        int i = 0;

        int length=0;


    while (word[i] != '\0'){
                i++;

           }

          length = i;

          char* temp_word = malloc(length* sizeof(char));

        for (i = 0; i < length; i++){

            temp_word[i] = word[length - i];

            word[i] = temp_word[i];

        }


        return word ;

    }
```

Comment: Hint: (unrelated to your code not working): you can reverse in place....

Comment: use a library string.h. but i am trying to do it without the library

Comment: No. not using a library!!!! In place means without any memory allocations....

Comment: oh yeah i know temporary array. i did that first it didn't work so i did this. dunno why same concept anyway. but its not working. can we focus on this specific error why do you people always veer off to some other issue

Comment: No! Not a temporary array!  !In place means in place.....You appear to not want any help.

Comment: Also you overwrite the first half of the string with the second one. The first one is then lost.

Answer (score 1):

```
temp_word[i] = word[length - i];
```

should probably be

```
temp_word[i] = word[length - i - 1];
```

If `word[]` is 3 characters long, `word[3]` is actually the null terminator.

Comment: The code still won't work even with this change, because it overwrites the first half of the string with the second half, and then copies it back over the second half, so for e.g. brick becomes kcick

Answer (score 1):

This works ... you did not allocate space for Null terminator ... and you are overwriting by doing this 'word[i] = temp_word[i]' ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


char *reverse(char *);


int main()
{
        char sWord[10] = "PHONE";
        char *temp = NULL;

        printf("Before reverse() => %s\n", sWord);

        temp = reverse(sWord);

        printf("After reverse() => %s\n", temp);

        return 0;
}


char *reverse(char *word)
{
        int i = 0;
        int length = 0;

        while(word[i] != '\0')
        {
                i++;
        }

        length = i;

        char *temp_word = malloc(length * (sizeof(char)+1)); // +1 here.

        for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
                temp_word[i] = word[length - (i+1)];
                //word[i] = temp_word[i]; <== Do not need this.
        }

        temp_word[length] = '\0';

        return temp_word ;
}
```